# Terraform - Adding Web Redirect URIs to an existing list on an Application Registration

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I have an interesting issue where I am trying to add additional Web Redirect URIs to an existing Application Registration in Azure.

I can get the values using the following:

```
data "azuread_application" "example_app" {
  display_name = "Appication_Registration"
}
```

When using this output block:

```
output "example_app_redirect_uris" {
  value = data.azuread_application.example_app.web.*.redirect_uris
}
```

The output looks like this:

```
example_app_redirect_uris = tolist([
  tolist([
    "https://customer01.domain.com/signin-microsoft",
    "https://customer01.domain.com/page/signin-microsoft",
  ]),
])
```

I am trying to add 2 values to this which would be:

```
    "https://customer02.domain.com/signin-microsoft",
    "https://customer02.domain.com/page/signin-microsoft",
```

I have tried using the concat command, but cannot seem to write this in to the web block.

Any advice or help would be greatly appreciated here.

Thanks in advance

Comment: " tried using the concat command" - please add the code that you tried along with errors that you get.

Answer (score 0):

> Terraform - Adding Web Redirect URIs to an existing list on an Application Registration

In order to update the **Application Registration** values using **Terraform**, the current configuration will be destroyed and a new application will be created, Follow the [Github](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azuread/issues/428) link by **AdamCoulterOz** for more details.

```
provider  "azurerm"  {
features  {}
}
provider  "azuread"  {}
data  "azuread_application"  "demoapplication"  {
application_id = "xxxxxx-b48d-4e6d-bfd4-29db3e79b56a"
}
resource  "azuread_application"  "existing_app_update"  {
display_name = data.azuread_application.demoapplication.display_name
web  {
redirect_uris = concat(
["https://example.com/redirect-uri-1",  "https://example.com/redirect-uri-6",  "https://example.com/redirect-uri-4"]
)
}
}
```

Alternatively, you can use **PowerShell** to update the **Redirect URIs** for an **Azure Application**.

```
        Connect-AzureAD
        $Adapp= Get-AzureADMSApplication -Filter "DisplayName eq 'demoapplication'"
       $appid= $Adapp.AppId
       $adobj =  $Adapp.Id
       $msalonly = 'msal'+$appid+'://auth'
   Set-AzureADMSApplication -ObjectId $Adapp.ID -PublicClient @{RedirectUris = "https://mynewapp.test.com/", $msalonly }
```

**Output**

[image]